# R qt equivalent in python

Tags: python, r, scipy

I have a R function which I am trying to convert in python using scipy

**R Func:**

```
lambda <- function(P) log(-log(P))
kt = function(x1, x2, n) suppressWarnings(qt(1 - x1, df = (n -1), ncp = (-sqrt(n) * lambda(x2))))
```

And here is the python equivalent that I have developed

**The python equivalent of R Func**

```
import scipy.stats as t
import nump as np
x = lambda P : np.log(-np.log(P))
kt = lambda x1,x2,n:(st.t.ppf(1 - x1, df = (n -1),scale=(-np.sqrt(n) * x(x2))))
```

Now I am testing both these function with the data:

```
kt(0.05,0.99,15)
```

I am getting a different result in python than R.

I think there is no parameter ncp in scipy ppf which is causing this issue.

Is there any python's equivalent function for R qt which I can use here with all the parameters of R such as df and ncp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `scipy.stats.nct` as shown in the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nct.html#scipy.stats.nct).